# Prove that a regular pentagon is cyclic

Tags: euclidean-geometry, circles, plane-geometry

> Prove that a regular pentagon is cyclic

I tried to use that every isosceles trapezoid is cyclic, so if you make a segment of some vertices that are not collinear you get an isosceles trapezoid and a triangle and both are cyclic, but I don't know how to relate them.

Comment: Several solutions appear to be in the web, e.g., [here](https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/prove-regular-polygon-cyclic-q9615293).

Comment: Hint: how far are the vertices from geometrical centre?

Comment: Another way to approach this is to construct a cyclic pentagon with the same central angles and verify that it is regular. Then finish the proof by showing that, up to scaling, all regular pentagons are congruent. For the first part you can take the points $(\cos((2pi+2k\pi)/5),\sin((2pi+2k\pi)/5))$, for $k=0,1,2,3,4$, which are on the unit circle, since $\cos^2+\sin^2=1$. They form a regular pentagon because all central angles are equal to $2\pi/5$. Now, if you scale it to have the same side as a given regular pentagon, then you can show that they are congruent by congruence of triangles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $ABCDE$ be our pentagon.

Thus, by your work ($ABCD$ and $ABCE$ are cyclics) $D$ and $E$ are placed on the circle $ABC$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $ABCDE$ be your regular pentagon. Let $\gamma$ be the circle passing through $ABC$, and let $O$ be the center of $\gamma$.

First, you can prove that the triangles $ABO$ and $BCO$ are congruent, because they have the same sides.

Then you can prove that the triangles $BCO$ and $CDO$ are congruent, using the fact that
$$BC \cong CD$$
$$BO \cong CO$$
$$\widehat{OBC}=\widehat{ABC}-\widehat{ABO} \cong  \widehat{BCD}-\widehat{BCO} =\widehat{OCD}$$

Thus $OD \cong OC$, and you proved that $D \in \gamma$.

In a similar way you can prove that $E \in \gamma$ as well, the proof repeats using the triangles $CDO$ and $DEO$.

EDIT: The same proof applies to any $N$-sided regular polygon $A_1 A_2 \ldots A_N$. You fix the circle $\gamma$ passing through $A_1, A_2, A_3$ and prove that $A_4 \in \gamma$. This means that $\gamma$ is the circle through $A_2, A_3, A_4$, and you prove that $A_5 \in \gamma$. Then repeat recursivley until you get $A_N \in \gamma$.

Answer (score 1):

All regular polygons are cyclic.  That's almost the definition.

Equiangular vertices and equal sides if and only if circumscribed and equal distance apart.

Because:

Take a side between two adjacent vertices $A,B$. The angles $\angle A$ and $\angle B$ are equal because the polygon is regular.  The measure of the angles are less then $180$ and in pentagon they are $108$.  Construct angle bisectors of $\angle A$ and $\angle B$. And the bisecteed angles are acute (in this case $54$ degrees) the bisectors will intersect at a point $O$ and $\triangle AOB$ is isosceles.

Now take the side between the adjacent vertices $B,C$ and bisect $\angle C$. The $P$ be the point where the angle bisector of $C$ intersects the angle bisector of $B$.  Then $\triangle BPC$ is isosceles.  And $AB = BC$ and as $\angle B \cong \angle C$ the base angles of the triangles are equal and the triangles are congruent.  So $BP = BO$ and $O=P$ and $O$ is the intersection of the the angle bisectors.

Do this of all sides and we conclude all angle bisectors intersect at $O$ and the distance from any vertex to $O$ is equal. Thus circumscribed.